# Изменение цвета элемента

Tags: java, android, color, android-animation

Пишу приложение, где по команде с боку (вместо бокового меню типа `NavigationDrawer`) будут выезжать кнопки переключения по `Activity`.

Вопрос: При выезде этих самых кнопок текущий `Activity` и элементы на нем должны затемнятся. Хочу сделать это изменением цвета элементов. Помогите пожалуйста с кодом для изменения цвета элемента!

Comment: Ваш вопрос не имеет к конкретной IDE (Android Studio) никакого отношения. Ваша задача решается абсолютно одинаково во всех IDE, поэтому упоминание Android Studio тут лишнее.

Comment: Поточнее опишите задачу и используемые виджеты для бокового меню. Способов много и они разнятся в зависимости от вышеозначенного.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. У меня например компонент расширяет `Button` и переопределяет `onDraw`:

```
Paint paintNotConnection = new Paint();
...
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(ConnectionError){
        paintNotConnection.setColor(Color.RED);
        paintNotConnection.setAlpha(100);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), paintNotConnection);
    }
}
```

Не забудьте вызвать `invalidate()` для перерисовки view.

Answer (score 1):

Советую не перерисовывать View, очень большая нагрузка на процесс, просто сделайте закрывашку с полупрозрачным цветом и меняйте видимость(setVisibility).

### Как альтернатива - попробуйте так:

Создаем `ColorDrawable` с полупрозрачным черным цветом:

```
ColorDrawable shadowColor;
```

...

```
frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout); //
shadowColor = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#99000000"));
```

Когда шторка открыта то:

```
frameLayout.setForeground(shadowColor);
```

Когда закрыта:

```
frameLayout.setForeground(null);
```